# Selenium v2.53.0 - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: selenium

I recently updated seleniumHQ from 2.47 to 2.53. Now it can't open anymore. I've made a printscreen of what I got.

On the internet I can't find information pertinent to my problem. Where can I get this class?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per Selenium [ChangeLog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG)

> ## v2.53.0
>
> FINAL 2.X RELEASE.
>
> No more HtmlUnitDriver... Moved to a subproject
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver

Selenium has removed it from the 2.53 onwards.

Download the html-unit driver from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases) and add it to your code

Comment: If I'm only running Selenium server for use with PHPUnit, how can I add the html-unit driver into selenium server? I'm asking because since I'm using PHP, I'm not sure how I can add that html unit driver into my php scripts.